# How to improve this regex to avoid PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR?

Tags: php, regex

I have following regex.

```
(From:.*)<(.+) (.+)@first abc.com>
```

And I am using following code to parse email address

```
$mimeFile = preg_replace_callback( "/(From:.*)<(.+) (.+)@first abc.com>/", 
function($matches) { 
    return $matches[1].'<'.strtolower($matches[2]).'.'.strtolower($matches[3]).'@xyz.com>'; 
}, $content );
```

It works for small content, but when content is large, it gives a PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR.

How can I improve my regex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `$content`?

Comment: Since when do email addresses start with `From:`? What are you _really_ matching with this regex?

Comment: @hek2mgl $content can be normal email content.

Comment: @Rawing I need to change web server name of email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$mimeFile = preg_replace_callback('~From:[^<\n]*<\K([^>@ ]+) ([^>@]+)@first abc\.com>~', function($m) { 
    return strtolower($m[1] . '.' . $m[2]) . '@xyz.com>'; 
}, $content );
```

The problem of your pattern comes from the use of consecutive `.*` or `.+` that are too permissive and that cause a [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) when the space or the substring `@first abc.com>` are not present.

In the two examples, instead of using `.+`, I use character classes that exclude the character where I need to stop. `[^@>]+` will stop as soon as `@` or `>` is encountered.

Note: When you write something like `[^a]+a`, the pcre regex engine automatically optimizes it as `[^a]++a` (it makes the quantifier [possessive](http://regular-expressions.info/possessive.html))

Comment: The reason for .+ is that string must have a space for correct match

Comment: @Sanky: In this case, it's better to use the second way.